# Authenticate with Kubernetes cluster with token

Tags: python, kubernetes

The way my environment is setup (AWS EKS) is that in my `~/.kube/config` the user has an exec configuration to make a call to `aws-iam-authenticator`.

This is so that when `kubectl` is run, it'll request the token to auth to the Kubernetes cluster.

I'm currently writing a client application that will interact with the Kubernetes API. This is written in Python, using the [official Python client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python).

When doing any of the examples, I get the error that `system:anonymous` isn't allowed to perform a certain operation (e.g. list pods). I think the root of the problem is that I need to pass a token from `aws-iam-authenticator` to my client requests.

Unfortunately I can't seem to figure out how to pass this token in with the Python client for Kubernetes. I see [this snippet](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/README.md#getting-started) but I get an error that `api_key` attribute isn't part of the `configuration` module (and sure enough, it isn't).

How am I supposed to inject the token into my requests from the Python client for Kubernetes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need the 'Authorization: Bearer ' header configured through this: `configuration.api_key_prefix['authorization'] = 'Bearer'`. So basically:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
import kubernetes.client
from kubernetes.client.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint

# Configure API key authorization: BearerToken
configuration = kubernetes.client.Configuration()
configuration.api_key['authorization'] = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
# Uncomment below to setup prefix (e.g. Bearer) for API key, if needed
configuration.api_key_prefix['authorization'] = 'Bearer' ## <== This one

# create an instance of the API class
api_instance = kubernetes.client.ApiregistrationV1Api(kubernetes.client.ApiClient(configuration))
body = kubernetes.client.V1APIService() # V1APIService | 
pretty = 'pretty_example' # str | If 'true', then the output is pretty printed. (optional)

try: 
    api_response = api_instance.create_api_service(body, pretty=pretty)
    pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling ApiregistrationV1Api->create_api_service: %s\n" % e)
```

It's basically described [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/ApiregistrationV1Api.md#create_api_service)